# Vignette: iframe to Included Document

Tags: r, package

I want to include an `iframe` call to a local html document in a package vignette.  The code for the vignette looks like this:

```
---
title: "Intro"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Intro}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
---

## Section 

<iframe src="insert.html" height="400", width="100%"></iframe>
```

I want the `iframe` to view the `insert.html` file in the same directory which could be any HTML file.

If I use `rmarkdown::render` all works as expected and I can see the `iframe` of the `insert.html`.  If I build the package and then install:

```
install.packages("SOdemoing_1.0.tar.gz", type="source")
browseVignettes(package = "SOdemoing")
```

The vignette's `iframe` is blank.

[image]

A look into the vignette folder `C:\R\R-3.1.2\library\SOdemoing\doc` showsthat the `insert.html` is not there so there's nothing for the `iframe` to source.

[image]

If I manually move `insert.html` into the `doc` directory the `iframe` works.  **How can I get R to build the vignette and place the `insert.html` file in the correct location (`doc`)?**

A MWE is difficult with package questions so I have made a GitHub mock package to demonstrate this: https://github.com/trinker/SOdemoing

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("trinker/SOdemoing")
```

Answer (score 1):

If one puts the `insert.html` in `inst/doc` it will be included in the `doc` file after the package is built.

http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_21.html

Comment: `ins/doc` or `inst/doc`?

Comment: @Dason the later.  Thanks-fixed.